# How to get 100% coverage test

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd, code-coverage

while doing TDD, I perform coverage and results looks like

```
Name        Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
royread.py   72     14    81%     84-85, 96-110
```

Actually I make test which import functions from other folder or one directory above. So when I generate the html , I realize that I got less coverage becauase 96-110 are function defintion lines. I mean below are lines which are skipped during coverage

```
if __name__ == '__main__':  
game_list = get_param(para1, para2) 
joystick_list = get_initial(para3, para4) 
mypath = get_path(game_list, joystick_list, test=True)
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
all_list = device_list["allList"] 
skip_start = device["header"]
```

I import these functions in the file where I worte my test functions and which start like

```
import unittest
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

from royread import get_param, get_initial,
from royread import mypath


class GameTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_get_param(self):
        device = "tekken"
        param = get_param(para1, para2)
        self.assertEqual(param["gamename"], "teken")
```

Can someone advice and help me to get more than 90% which is possible if it does not neglect function defintion lines. 
Thanks you very much for any tip or example.

Comment: What's inside a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block will only run if that Python module is invoked directly. It is not executed by any test runner.

Comment: I perform test coverage with this.       coverage run -m nose -v
                    then                                coverage report -m royread.py
Instead of running the coverage on test file I am doing this on file which includes this main block. and results are mention above, it skipped the function definition lines.

Comment: Is there any way/ advice how to solve this issue to get maximum coverage.

Comment: I got 84% coverage and the solution i applied is to neglect those function definition lines by using configuration lines. the link is here. http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html

Comment: sorry configuration file not lines

Comment: 84 % because i add new function in my test file and test coverage was about 75 % , by neglecting those function definition lines in test coverage, it increases to 84 % which is better i guess.

Comment: Try to focus on test quality over coverage. Using TDD & writing good test cases that cover a range of inputs will automatically produce a very high coverage stat. A suite of quality tests is better for example, than a single test case that just covers code. CodeCoverage != CodeQuality

Answer (score 0):

I got 84% coverage and the method i applied is to neglect those function definition lines by using configuration file. the link is here. http://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html